# Alarm Manager doesn't trigger on time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create app where i need to send location updates every 1,5,10 minutes and so on.

When app is running, it work accurately but when it goes into ***background/sleep mode*** it doesn't work accurately.

I tried both the methods `setRepeating/setInExactRepeating` but none of them work in background mode.

```
 public static void startSensorAlaram(Context ctx, long minutes) {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

     // Alarm_Receiver is a broadcast receiver.

    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Alaram_Receiver.class);

    intent.setAction(Utility.SENSOR_ACTION);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),minutes,pi);

 // alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), minutes, pi);

}

public static void stopAlaramSensor(Context ctx) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Alaram_Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1,
            intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

}
```

**`Alarm Receiver - Broadcast receiver`**

```
public class Alaram_Receiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    sp = context.getSharedPreferences(Utility.SHARED_PREFS, 0);

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.SENSOR_ACTION)) {

        if (sp.getBoolean("logged_in", false)) {

        // context.startService(new Intent(context,SensorService.class));

         startWakefulService(context,new Intent(context,SensorService.class));

        } else
            Utility.stopAlaramSensor(context);
    }
  }
}
```

*`Note:-`* ***Min API version is 15 and compile version is 23.***

Comment: Which version of Android running on your test device?

Comment: It's android 5.1 and 6.0 @nuuneoi

Comment: Please consult the docs for [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). As of KitKat, if your `targetSdkVersion`>=19, `setRepeating()` is inexact. You need to use `setExact()`, and set the alarm again for the desired interval each time it fires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues.

1) As of Android API >= 19, you should use new `AlarmManager.setExact()` method instead of `set()` or `setRepeating()`. Here is the quote from official document.

> Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will
>   shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are
>   new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).

2) As of Android 6.0, there is a deep sleep mode introduced, called `Doze`.

It is designed to reduce battery consumption when device is being standby. There are so many restriction and what you could do in that mode is very limited. You need to use the new `AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` to make Alarm fired in Doze mode at your preferred time.

More information about Doze mode is available here [Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Comment: can we use handler.postDelayed() in Doze Mode? @nuuneoi

Comment: Nope. You cannot. Most of the processes are forced into sleep mode including Thread-job like Handler.

Comment: I want to get device location using alarm manager and send to our server all the time. isn't that possible now with doze? Looks like alarm manager accuracy is working. is that something you can help here?